# Is it safe to import bookmarks?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, browsers

Is is safe to import bookmarks from another browser into the Tor Browser? How can I import my bookmarks if it is safe?

I have not tried anything because I am not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is using Pinned Tabs and Bookmarks bad for Tor Browser?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/is-using-pinned-tabs-and-bookmarks-bad-for-tor-browser)

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is no, don't import preexisting bookmarks.

The long answer is *it depends*.

[URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (the web address data stored in browser 'bookmarks') are pretty flexible in their format and often contain embedded information of various sorts. While this additional data is typically appended to a URL (ie: any part of a URL that comes after a '?') there are many URLs that have identifying information included in the path or even the subdomain.

If you have any doubt that the URL that are you using is not a general address applicable for everyone, assume that there is identifying information embedded in it.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT IMPORT, unless your $HOME is encrypted..

I usually store stuff on a encrypted partition, which is different from the `/home/user/` The bookmarks are stored in

```
~/.local/share/torbrowser 
~/.cache/torbrowser/
```

so unless that is encrypted there is no point importing bookmarks

Comment: But the encrypted partition is mounted in a temporary, unencrypted space when in use. Using encryption here would only protect against hard-drive theft. Other than that, I see no harm in using unencrypted storage.