# Can creating bookmark in TBB add any security risk for user?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

Can Creating bookmark in TBB add any security risk for user? Can anybody read  any of these bookmarks remotely?

Comment: This question might be helpful for you. The answer covers probably also your question: http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1303/88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bookmarks cannot be read remotely (but see below). However, anyone that gains physical access to your computer can read them, of course.

The above statement about cannot be read remotely is not entirely correct. As mentioned [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/is-it-safe-to-import-bookmarks) (as pointed out by Jens Kubieziel), if your bookmark is not an trivial URL (like https://duckduckgo.com), it may contain a unique identifier that enables the server you connect to to know you are the same one from before.

A non-trivial URL may look like https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi&ei=AtjnUrO_MuXjywPXy4IQ&ved=0CAQQqi4oAg. You don't know if that extra stuff is a unique number for you (it probably is). Even just a simple number after the / may be unique to you.

Comment: Could you give an example of not an trivial URL?

Comment: Done. Updated the answer.