# Can bookmarks set in the TBB (or Firefox) be used for Fingerprinting? Is it safe to use bookmarks?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security

Bookmarks are (for me) a handy feature to keep track of notable sites in the internet.

Does the Tor Browser Bundle (and does that differ from the way Firefox behaves?)
offer the bookmarks saved during sessions to webservices to be read?

How actually do bookmarks differ from cookies or the installed addons in the way they reveal themselves (awful english...) to people who are not the User?

Is it safe to use bookmarks (including across multiple sessions)?
(pretend the system this is happening on is not compromised)

(could you crate the tag bookmarks or bookmark please?)

Comment: I always understood bookmarks to be like shortcuts and to be safe. I use them on the Tor Browser. I would be supprised to learn otherwise. Check the following thread for more information [https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/can-creating-bookmark-in-tbb-add-any-security-risk-for-user?rq=1](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/can-creating-bookmark-in-tbb-add-any-security-risk-for-user?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your bookmarks are not transmitted to a web server in a http request.

I don't know whether they can be queried through java script. (I hope not, but it wouldn't surprise me. Maybe someone who knows this for a fact can comment.)

They will, of course, give away your browsing habits to someone with access to your browser.

Comment: Not necessarily give away browsing habits, jut websites you have bookmarked (you might want to bookmark .onion sites more than clearnet sties, but that doesn't mean that you visit those sites more)