# Is using Pinned Tabs and Bookmarks bad for Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security

There are some onion sites I want to keep track of but the URLs are so long. Is using pinned tabs and bookmarks a secure option? Will people be able to track me if I set bookmarks or pin some tabs?

Comment: Define safe? This question is a bit broad as is. What threats are you trying to protect against? Please improve the question and then vote to have it re-opened. For more info see "[How do I ask a good question?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" in the help center.

Comment: I edited this to be more on point.

Comment: Works for me; now that we know you're trying to find out about fingerprinting and tracking it should be easier to help you. Thanks! (I went ahead and reopened it because the community is still fairly slow at review/moderation tasks; this will improve over time as we gain more active users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Internet security and anonimacy: You're almost safe, unless NSA cracks into your computer to spy your Bookmarks and session files.

About Computer being secure: You're not safe, since you are leaving tracks on your hard disk about which sites do you visit.

So if your computer has any risk of being seized by NSA, FBI, Communist Party of China, Guardians of the Revolution, or your mother, do not use Bookmarks nor pinned tabs. On the other hand, if you feel you are locally safe, do whatever you wish.

Comment: Okay I'll just make a pinned tab for a .onion search engine :) thanks